# R: how to interpret the gray bars in the plotted output of the decompose function for time series?

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

In order to do some time series analysis, I used the decompose() function, to retrieve the adjacent plot.

However, I was asking myself about the meaning of the gray bars at the right side. If the show the importance of each time series component, then I do not understand, why there is also a gray bar for the original time series in the plot.

Maybe some does know it. Could not find it in any documentation.

[image]

Comment: How did you get that plot?  For example `plot(decompose(co2))` does not produce the grey bars on the right

Comment: All the grey bars seem to be about $2300$ in height so may just be an indicator of scale

Comment: @Henry That's (probably) the output of `forecast:::autoplot.decomposed.ts`. You're correct: they indicate scale, and they are not displayed in `stats::plot.decomposed.ts`, which could be misleading (e.g. it looks like the data is seasonal but the seasonal component is actually very small and not important). The default height of the bar is the range of the component with the smallest range (the seasonal component in this case).

Comment: Yes, it was produced with autoplot. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The grey bars to the right of each panel show the relative scales of the components. Each grey bar represents the same length but because the plots are on different scales, the bars vary in size."

Ref: https://otexts.com/fpp2/components.html, second paragraph below Figure 6.2.

Below, I've scaled **down** the graph of the remainder component (in pink) so the scale bar is the same size as the scale bar of the data and overlaid it on the data. Now the bars are the same size, you can clearly see how the remainder component relates to the data.

If you look at the seasonal component, you can see the bar is longer than that of the remainder component so the remainder component would have to be scaled **up** if it were overlaid on the seasonal component.

[image: comparison]

Comment: Greetings! This answer is a little short and doesn't provide a ton of context. I would add some information explaining this in more detail so it's more clear how this answers the question.